# how to add another column to query result?

Tags: mysql, datatable, count

i need some help.

so i have one table like this.

| id_num | payment  | dollar |

| 889    | 1/2/2022 | 500    |

| 889    | 3/2/2022 | 400    |

| 789    | 1/2/2022 | 350    |

| 123    | 2/1/2022 | 200    |

I want to count how many unique Id_num with their payment date.

i'm using this query

```
select id_num, count(*) as count from tabletesting Group By id_num ;
```

And the result was

| id_num | count |

| 889    |   2   |

| 789    |   1   |

| 123    |   1   |

What i want is something like this

| id_num | payment  | count |

| 889    | 1/2/2022 |   2   |

| 889    | 3/2/2022 |   2   |

| 789    | 1/2/2022 |   1   |

| 123    | 2/1/2022 |   1   |

how could i achieve that result ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try this query

```
select id_num, payment,
(
select count(*) as count 
from tabletesting b
where b.id_num = a.id_num
group by id_num
) as 'count'
from tabletesting a
group by id_num, payment
```

I hope it help

Comment: Well, almost. the count didn't work like my expectation. All count results was 1 1 1 1, same id_num didn't show as 2 count. :(

Comment: i've just updated my answer ,
can u plz check it and let me know if it works

Comment: I wouldn't use a group by without aggregation - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html and in this case a subquery is unnecessary and you can't alias a column in a group by clause..

Comment: well, i'm getting error . . . the right syntax to use near 'b
) as 'count'
from tabletesting a
group by id_num, payment LIMIT 0, 25' . . . Sorry for bothering you

Comment: sorry, im such an idiot, i've updated my answer again

Comment: And, Voila,  It match my expectation. Thank you very much sir. That's worked. :D